# Firebase security rules: Allow read on anything except one field

Tags: firebase

In my Firebase security rules, I want anonymous users to be able to read anything except one field (`secret_field`):

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": "auth != null",
    "stuff" : {
      "$stuffID" : {
        "secret_field" : {
           ".read" : "auth != null"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, in Firebase, if any read rule on the way to `secret_field` evaluates as true, read access on `secret field` is granted.

Is there a way to reverse that behavior? (If any read rule on the way to `secret_field` evaluates to false, disallow read access)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't reverse the behavior, but you can solve this by introducing a "container" for the public fields and setting .read to true for it.  For example:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "stuff" : {
      "$stuffID" : {
        "public" : {
          ".read": true
        },
        "secret_field" : {
          ".read" : "auth != null"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And then everything under .../public/ is accessible to everybody but .../secret_field is only accessible for authenticated users.

Comment: what if you wanted to iterate over each 'stuff' would that be possible without revealing the 'secret_field'? As I understand the above this path is inaccessible: `/stuff/`. Only `/stuff/<someid>/public` is possible.

Comment: Right.  You wouldn't be able to iterate the items under "stuff."  If you need that, you'll need to restructure your data slightly.  You could put ".read": true on the "stuff" list and then move the "secret_field" data into its own tree.  E.g. have /stuff/$stuffID for public data and put the secret data in /secret_stuff/$stuffID/ (and have an appropriate .read rule there).

Comment: @MichaelLehenbauer thanks for the answer, it'd be better if this information was on the docs.

Comment: I'm following a similar approach, except that I duplicate the data. A `private` tree has all the data, and a `public` tree also has all the data minus the "secret fields". Is this a good  approach? Querying the public data is easier in this way, since it doesn't depend on the private data. However, an issue I run into is keeping those two trees in sync. For example when an authenticated user modifies the data, the public fields of that data need to be updated as well. I can't think of a simple way to do that since, I'm currently just doing `$firebaseArray.$save()` to save the data in a list.